# New Column in report view NOT returning correct value

Tags: powerbi, dax

My data is a list of incoming deliveries from different cities.[Incoming]

My reference table has a list of Bays allocated to different cities.[Bay Allocation]

Many to one relationship.

My report has a list of the cities and the relevant Bay.

In report view I want add an extra column that puts "Not Allocated" where there is a blank bay.

Column = IF('Bay Allocation'[Bay]="","No Allocation",'Bay Allocation'[Bay])

However it is only returning a result where the Bay number already exists.

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a way of doing this or do I need to merge queries and do it that way?

Thanks for your patience and time in advance.

Comment: Perhaps, in the cells that appear empty, there is something other than `""`

Comment: They are null as they have no reference. In the visual above I do not have a bay for Washington therefore in my report it will be blank.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem from the information you have provided. Perhaps you could develop a sample file that demonstrates the problem and upload it to some sharing site, posting a link here.

Comment: Once again, the IsBlank() formula works, but isn't referencing where there is a blank (or missing reference)

Answer (score 1):

You can't consider a "blank" field as "".
Try something like this:

IF(ISBLANK('Bay Allocation'[Bay]),"No Allocation",'Bay Allocation'[Bay])

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/isblank-function-dax